# Laravel using 2 unique field in Validator()

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I want my users not to have the same  Username and Account Number these are 2 unique fields, I already have an existing database without using the migration.

RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $username = Request::input('Username');
        $accountnum = Request::input('AccountNum');

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'Username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:UsersInfo,Username,'.$username],
            'FirstName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'LastName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'AccountNum' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:UsersInfo,AccountNum,'.$accountnum],
            'MobileNum' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'Address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
```

Every time I register I got this error

```
SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'user29' to data type int. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [UsersInfo] where [Username] = user29 and [id] <> user29)
```

But when I remove `'unique:UsersInfo,Username,',$username` it works with the Account Number it will give an error that it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "different" rule.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-different

Comment: I should use different rules for each field?

Comment: I tried `Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('account_id', 1);
        }),
    ],
]);` and it did work! Thank you so much!